# docker run and get exited (253)

Tags: docker

I tring run docker rocketmq

```
docker run --name rmqbroker -d -p 10911:10911 -p 10909:10909   -v  /root/deployment/rocketmq/broker/logs:/home/rocketmq/logs -v  /root/deployment/rocketmq/broker/store:/home/rocketmq/store -v  /root/deployment/rocketmq/broker/conf/broker.conf:/opt/rocketmq/broker.conf  -e "NAMESRV_ADDR=192.168.142.100:9876" -e "MAX_POSSIBLE_HEAP=200000000" rocketmqinc/rocketmq:4.4.0 sh mqbroker -c /opt/rocketmq/broker.conf
```

but I exits without running:

```
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                                          NAMES
089fbec3e3e0        rocketmqinc/rocketmq:4.4.0   "sh mqbroker -c /o..."   30 minutes ago      Exited (253) 30 minutes ago
```

and no any log

Comment: What is the output of `docker logs {{container_id}}`?

Comment: Don’t detach your container, I mean remove the “-d” option and check the logs whether there is any errors

Answer (score 0):

权限问题
文件挂载修改权限
chown -R 3000:3000 /root/deployment/rocketmq